# docker build RUN error while loading shared libraries

Tags: docker, sh, libc

I am having trouble making a simple build run on my RHEL server.

When running `docker build` I get

```
Step 2/2 : RUN echo "Hello there!"
 ---> Running in 0d0fd7f69a5f

/bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c echo "Hello there!"' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN echo "Hello there!"
```

RHEL 7.7 - Linux 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64

Docker version 1.13.1, build 4ef4b30/1.13.1

The Dockerfile is fine - I can build the image on any other machine so I am wondering where the issue actually is. Thanks!

Comment: Does `echo "Hello world"` work on the RHEL terminal?

Comment: have you tried ```RUN sudo echo "Hello there!"``` ?

Comment: Try doing `docker pull ubuntu`; plausibly your local `ubuntu` image has been pointed at something else.

Comment: `echo "Hello world"` works. `sudo` does not help. `docker pull ubuntu` says `Image is up to date for docker.io/ubuntu:latest`

Comment: Can you do this check in your host machine? https://access.redhat.com/solutions/323023

Comment: Added an answer - thanks for the help! Was an SELinux issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the suggestions!

Turns out it was an SELinux issue. Seems Docker needs SELinux to be configured properly to run (in my case I chose to disable SELinux using `sudo setenforce 0`).